# Google Maps API - PlacesAutocomplete types issue

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm currently working on an app with `GoogleMaps API` using their `PlacesAutocomplete` plugin to fill an input.

The problem which I encountered is that for the result `types` for Airports I get only `establishment`. I tried using `establishment` and `geocode` for parameters in the API call but with no luck. I either get only `establishment` or maximum `transit_station` in the results. The problem with `transit_station` is that all the train stations, airports, bus stations are marked the same.

I need a way to get the specific type for each of them, could someone help me please, maybe I'm doing something wrong.

You can see in the screenshot below the result from the `API`
[image: API Result with establishment set as type parameter in the call]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, currently the types parameter of places autocomplete supports only following values:

```
geocode
address
establishment
(regions)
(cities)
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#add_autocomplete

LE: Found a workaround

In order to get the place type I used another `API` this time `Place Details`

I took the `placeId` from the `Autocomplete` request and fired a new request to the `Place Details` with the `fields` parameter set to `types`

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=[YOUR_KEY]&placeid=ChIJRQFUJVRhRUcR-C4yT1Y4KWk&fields=type
```

And the result was

```
{
    "html_attributions": [],
    "result": {
        "types": [
            "airport",
            "point_of_interest",
            "establishment"
        ]
    },
    "status": "OK"
}
```

So by combining the two calls I  was able to get even the type which in the `Autocomplete` was not available

The docs for the the `Place Details` can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details)